# Error while sourcing slam_gmapping in ROS Melodic

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have got the slam_gmapping package from https://github.com/OpenSLAM-org/openslam_gmapping.git
Now when I try to source the workspace in ROS Melodic, I get the following output, which is throwing an error:

```
shaunak@robokits:~/catkin_ws$ rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
slam_gmapping: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [openslam_gmapping]
gmapping: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [openslam_gmapping]
```

I also tried [https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping.git](https://github.com/OpenSLAM-org/openslam_gmapping.git), but came to know that it is built till ROS Hydro only.

Am I facing this issue due to my latest ROS Melodic Version? Is there any slam_gmapping source available for ROS Melodic? If yes, kindly share it.

---

Edit: @gvdhoorn : Thank you for sharing #q300480. I have not used docker yet. In fact, it's a new term for me. I was about to execute the following commands:

```
$ docker run -it --rm ros:melodic
(docker) $ apt update
(docker) $ rosdep update
(docker) $ mkdir -p /ros_ws/src
(docker) $ cd /ros_ws
(docker) $ git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/openslam_gmapping src/openslam_gmapping
(docker) $ git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping src/slam_gmapping
(docker) $ rosdep install --from-paths src/ -i
(docker) $ catkin_make
```

But I had to `sudo`  the `docker run -it --rm ros:melodic`  command and it ended like this:

```
shaunak@robokits:~$ sudo docker run -it --rm ros:melodic
root@583c78ce75be:/#
```

instead of

```
$ docker run -it --rm ros:melodic
(docker) $
```

Please confirm whether I should proceed further or not.

I also want to know, if I can work in `root@583c78ce75be:/#` ,  whether I can use my already existing workspace instead of creating a new one as per here. If I can not, then I can not work on my existing workspace that has many other packages as well. So kindly clarify it because as per my understanding, I find no point in setting up two different workspaces having separate sections of my packages.

Shaunak Agastya Vyas (TINU)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304988/error-while-sourcing-slam_gmapping-in-ros-melodic/) by [Shaunak Vyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/37404/shaunak-vyas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2018-10-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-06**:
Please do not post answers if you're not answering your own question. This is not a forum and AskBot works a bit differently.

To interact with other posts, use comments, or *edit* your original question (use the `edit` button/link for that).

**Comment by [Shaunak Vyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/37404/shaunak-vyas/) on 2018-10-08**:
Ok. I had to respond with long text and the comment section has limit, so I chose to answer. Anyways, point noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see #q300480.

Note also btw: "sourcing a package" is not vernacular that is used in ROS. Only workspaces can be `source`d.

Also: the upstream `openslam_gmapping` repository that you found is not a ROS package, so you cannot use it directly.

---

Edit:

> I have not used docker yet. In fact, it's a new term for me.

there is no need to use Docker.

I just used it in #q300480 to test out whether I could build `gmapping` from source without polluting my own system.

You can just run the two `git clone ..` commands and the `rosdep install ..` command in and on your regular workspace.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shaunak Vyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/37404/shaunak-vyas/) on 2018-10-08**:
It works as per #q300480. A very small difference between docker and my user was that I had to `shaunak@robokits:~$ mkdir -p ~/ros_catkin_ws/src` in terminal instead of `(docker) $ mkdir -p /ros_ws/src` in docker because `shaunak@robokits:~$ mkdir -p /ros_catkin_ws/src` created folder in root.